# Anyone connected a Salesforce org to e.g. Loggly or DataDog?

Tags: platform-event, logging

Cloud-based logging environments provide tools to help analyze log files.

We are looking at using Platform Events as one of the outputs of our logging calls per [Logging frameworks that use Platform Events - what is the full list?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/291721/logging-frameworks-that-use-platform-events-what-is-the-full-list), and given that those events can be consumed via CometD/Bayeux, are hoping that some of the cloud-based logging services are easy to connect to, but so far have not found that to be the case.

Has anyone connected e.g. https://www.loggly.com/ or https://www.datadoghq.com/ to their Platform Events?

Comment: Is it good idea to use event bus for logging purpose?
Yo have 50k limit per license and it is meant to push data to down system... not logs

Comment: hey @KeithC, I was wondering if you managed to integrate them :)

Comment: Hi @markgarg, no never progressed this.

Comment: Hey @KeithC, did you manage to sort this out? Am looking into https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/salesforce/ without event monitoring with just custom platform events to have my own dashboards and monitoring in datadog

Comment: Hi @PranayJaiswal, No I didn't.

Comment: @KeithC okay!! so we cant connect our custom platform events. only events subrived by datadog are not customer data sensetive events,

I managed to use `platform events-> eventbridge->cloudwatch logs->datadog `

not ideal but gets job done